# ripple counter in vhdl with 3 flip flops d

Tags: vhdl

I dont have any idea of how to do this, I've done the code of one FF d, i dont know how to put 3 of them in one process. I am not allow to use component or describing them separetely.

[image]

I tried to search but unfortunately i coudn´t find anything.
sorry if anything is writing wrong, english is my second lenguage and VHDL id pretty new :)

this is the code i have so far,

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


entity pr3 is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           init : in STD_LOGIC;
           areset : in std_logic;
           dividendo : in unsigned(7 downto 0);
           divisor : in unsigned(7 downto 0);
           mod_out : out unsigned(7 downto 0));
end pr3;

architecture RT of pr3 is
signal acum: unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal resta: unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal comp: std_logic;
signal mux: unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal load: std_logic;

signal Q: std_logic;
signal P_logic: std_logic;
signal Q1,Q2,Q3: std_logic;
signal init_out: std_logic;

begin
    load <=init_out or comp;
    acum_process: process(clk, areset)
    begin
        if (clk'event and clk='1') then
            if(load = '1') then 
                acum <= mux;
                else acum <= acum;
            end if;
        end if;
        if(areset = '1') then
            acum <= "00000000";
        end if;
    end process;
    
    mux_process: process(init_out,resta,dividendo)
    begin
    if (init_out = '1') then
        mux <= dividendo;
    else 
        mux <= resta;
    end if;
    end process;
    
    resta_process: process(acum,divisor)
    begin
    resta <= acum - divisor;
    end process;
    
    comp_process: process(acum,divisor)
    begin
    if ( acum > divisor) then
        comp <= '1';
    else 
        comp <= '0';
    end if;
    end process;
    
    
    FlipFlop1:process(areset, clk, init)
    begin
         if( areset = '1') then
            Q1<= '0';
         elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then
           Q1<= init;
         end if;
    
    end process;
    mod_out<=acum;
    
end RT;
```

hope that you can help.

Comment: Other than the FlipFlop1 process what does the above code have to do with a ripple counter?  Why is the code included here? Is this intended for behavioral simulation or eventual synthesis? If synthesis which vendor and tool version? What is the purpose of the ripple counter? (What will it be used for?)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing assigns your `init_out` internal signal, so all this cannot work.

Anyway, VHDL is a high-level programming language, not a gate-level structural language. As your design has only one output which is also the output of an 8-bits register you can model all this in one single synchronous process that directly reflects your schematic:

```vhdl
architecture rt of pr3 is
begin

  process(clk, areset)
  begin
    if areset = '1' then
      mod_out <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
      if init = '1' then
        mod_out <= dividendo;
      elsif mod_out > divisor then
        mod_out <= mod_out - divisor;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

end architecture rt;
```

If, for any reason, you really want to split your design as shown in your schematic you can still manipulate multi-bits vectors as a whole, and use concurrent signal assignments instead of the much more verbose equivalent processes:

```vhdl
architecture rt of pr3 is
  signal restador, next_mod_out: unsigned(7 downto 0);
  signal load, comp: std_ulogic;
begin

  comp <= '1' when mod_out > divisor else '0';

  load <= init or comp;

  restador <= mod_out - divisor;

  next_mod_out <= dividendo when init = '1' else restador;

  process(clk, areset)
  begin
    if areset = '1' then
      mod_out <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
      if load = '1' then
        mod_out <= next_mod_out;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

end architecture rt;
```